# Asking for user's input multiple times with loop in C

Tags: c, pointers, input, struct, while-loop

With this beginner's code, I am trying to ask the user for input as long as the input is not 'quit'. My code:

```
void createReport(){
    printf("Welcome to the report generator, type item's ID: ");
    char *userInput;
    int i=0;
    struct myStruct{
        char *name;
        int id;
        float sale;
    };
    struct myStruct *myStructArray[MAX_ITEMS];
    fgets(userInput,sizeof(int),stdin);
    while(strcmp(userInput,"quit")!=0) {
        userInput = malloc(sizeof(int));
        fgets(userInput,sizeof(int),stdin);
        searchA(userInput); //different function that changes global variable deletion
        printf("Added to the report, add more or type \'quit\' \n");
        strcpy(myStructArray[i]->name,inventoryItem[deletion].name);  //inventoryItem is global
        myStructArray[i]->id = atoi(input);
        myStructArray[i]->sale = inventoryItem[deletion].sale;
        i++;
        free(userInput);
    }
    for(int x=0;x<30;x++) printf(myStructArray[x]->name);  //never executed
}
```

This code runs once, asking the user for input, and then finishes[image]

Does anybody know where can be the mistake? Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: your `userInput` is invalid when your using with `fgets` or `strcmp` .

Comment: Also `userInput = malloc(sizeof(int));` will not be enough to hold even `quit` considering `sizeof(int)` as 4 bytes.

Comment: yeah, didn't think about that, let's say I allocate it enough of memory, but what do you mean by is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Before the `while` loop you do

```
fgets(userInput,sizeof(int),stdin);
```

at that moment your variable `userInput` is not yet to be set.

## Edit:

Running example of the idea of the code:

```
printf("Welcome to the report generator, type item's ID: ");
const int input_size = 6 * sizeof(char);
char *userInput = malloc(input_size);
int i = 0;
struct myStruct {
    char *name;
    int id;
    float sale;
};
struct myStruct *myStructArray[MAX_ITEMS];

fgets(userInput, input_size, stdin);
while (strcmp(userInput, "quit") != 0 && strcmp(userInput, "quit\n") != 0) 
{
    // do whatever you like with myStructArray[i], for example:
    myStructArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));
    myStructArray[i]->name = malloc(sizeof(char));
    myStructArray[i]->name = "ab";
    myStructArray[i]->id = 7;
    myStructArray[i]->sale = 99.9F;
    printf("Added %s, %d, %f\n", myStructArray[i]->name, myStructArray[i]->id, myStructArray[i]->sale);

    //prepare for next iteration:
    printf("Added to the report, add more or type \'quit\' \n");
    for (int j = 0; j < input_size; ++j) // zeroing allocated data on the heap
        userInput[j] = 0;

    fgets(userInput, input_size, stdin);
    i++;
}
free(userInput);
for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) printf("%s,", myStructArray[x]->name);
```

Comment: well I have `char *userInput` there, is that not enough?

Comment: `*userInput` is not yet initialized at this point.
And another issue is you allocate memory for it each loop, it is possible but a waste.
I will edit my answer to give you a fixed version of the code.

Comment: so I tried to debug the code and I get a segmentation fault when doing  `strcpy(myStructArray[i]->name,inventoryItem[deletion].name); ` I think this may be the issue

Comment: I can not guess the problem in using variables I don't see.
If you put the whole relevant code, including: `inventoryItem`, `deletion`, `searchA(...)`

I could see where the problem and suggest a good solution.